# I get "reference error: user is not defined" when i delete my jwt token

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I want to make authentication system with my express-ejs template, using jwt. I created a cookie, i see that in the cookies section and i send it to the front side. When that cookie is exist, i could write it successfully on the screen but for testing reasons, for see what happening when user is offline, i deleted that cookie and i get that reference error.

I try to conditionally write that user data like this:

```
    <% if (!user) { %>
        <h2> Hello Guest! </h2>
    <% } else { %>
        <h2> Hello <%= user.username %></h2>
    <% } %>
```

But i get that error in first line. I don't understand anything, i'm already try to check if it's undefined or not but take that error which the thing i checked. I set that cookie's "HTTPOnly" property as "true", i don't know if it because of that. When that cookie exist ejs renders the infos of that cookie but when isn't exist it's not check if it's undefined or not.

I send user to the front-end with this code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9jas.png)

```
server.get("/", function(req, res, next){
if(!req.headers.cookie){
    res.render("home")
} else{
    console.log("headers:", req.headers.cookie.split("=")[1]);
    console.log("jwt decoding:", jwt.decode(req.headers.cookie.split("=")[1]))
    let user = jwt.decode(req.headers.cookie.split("=")[1])
    res.render("home", { user });
}
```

});

Comment: Show how you pass the var `user` to ejs

Comment: i append that code @Anatoly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have to pass the variable to the view, but leave it empty:

```js
server.get("/", function(req, res, next){
if(!req.headers.cookie){
    res.render("home", { user: null })
} else{
    console.log("headers:", req.headers.cookie.split("=")[1]);
    console.log("jwt decoding:", jwt.decode(req.headers.cookie.split("=")[1]))
    let user = jwt.decode(req.headers.cookie.split("=")[1])
    res.render("home", { user });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't pass a variable called "user" to your EJS template.

You can check against the existance of a variable like so:

```
<% if (typeof(user) === 'undefined') { %>
    <h2> Hello Guest! </h2>
<% } else { %>
    <h2> Hello <%= user.username %></h2>
<% } %>
```